# Jackson error parser trying resolve a sub type but my class is a simple POJO

Tags: java, spring, jackson-databind

msg error:

```
{
    "@class": "java.util.LinkedHashMap",
    "timestamp": [
        "java.util.Date",
        "2018-10-04T17:12:35.742+0000"
    ],
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class br.com.adtsys.ciee.auth.user.data.request.LoginRequest]: missing type id property '@class'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class br.com.adtsys.ciee.auth.user.data.request.LoginRequest]: missing type id property '@class'\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 1]",
    "path": "/auth/login"
}
```

but my class is a simple POJO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LoginRequest implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

This object is a parameter in my controller where I'm doing a request on a POST method and that object is annotated with @Body annotation and when I call the rest endpoint spring try to convert my JSON in my object, but that error happens. I'm using jackson library embedded in spring boot version 2.0.5, that error started to happen after I upgraded my spring-boot verstion 1.5.3 to 2.0.5.
I already searched about this problem, but unfortunately nothing until now.
Someone knows something about this problem.

Comment: Are you using lombok? or what's the origin for those Getter, Setter annotations?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide the json for which you get the response above, and also the mentioned rest endpoint.

Comment: Yes I'm using lombok

Comment: {
 "username": "000001",
 "password": "adminciee2017"
}

Comment: I found the problem, when I send my JSON i need to put :
{
 "@class": "br.com.adtsys.ciee.auth.user.data.request.LoginRequest",
 "username": "000001",
 "password": "adminciee2017"
}
I don't now why I must have to send the class name. I believe which I can disable that requirement to parse my JSON. I need to search more